# Implement two stack in one array

Tags: arrays, data-structures, stack

How to implement two stack in one array A[1..n] in such a way that neither stack overflows unless total no. of elements in both stack together is n. PUSH and POP should run in O(1) time ?

What's wrong with this algo ?

```
//A[1...n], top1 is pointer pointing to top of stack1.

top1=-1;
top2=-1;

STACK-EMPTY(A)

1. if(top1==0 && top2==0)
2.    return 1
3. else
4.    return 0

STACK-FULL(A)

1.  if(top1==S1.length && top2==S1.length)
2.     return 1
3.  else if(top1==S1.length)
4.     return -1
5.  else  if(top2==S2.length)
6.     return -2
7.  else
8.     return 0

PUSH (A,x)
1.  if(!STACK-FULL())
2.      if(STACK-FULL()==-1)
3.          top2=top2+1
4.          S2[top2]=x
5.      else if(STACK-FULL()==-2)
6.          top1=top1+1
7.          S1[top1]=x
8.      else
9.          top1=top1+1   
10.         S1[top1]=x
11. else
12.    OVERFLOW
```

Comment: Fill the array from opposite ends. top1 = 1 and top2 = n. When PUSH is called with top1 = top2, overflow. POP1 needs to only decrement top1, and POP2 needs to only increment POP2.

Comment: That I know..but I was searching another implementation of "one array two stack..". So a I am asking "Is this algo satisfy above conditions of O(1) time and Overflow "?

Comment: line 1 of STACK-FULL doesn't make sense

Comment: Yeah..sorry..typing mistake.. Its if(top1==S1.length && top2==S2.length)

Comment: Fix your formatting! Edit your question and format the code as normal code rather than using numbered lists. If you indent lines 4 or more spaces, they will display as code. Take some time to read the editing help if you want people to read and respond to your questions.

Comment: Jim Mischel sir I was not writing code. I was writing algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to implement it this way that both stacks start from left side of the array. Push and pop won`t be O(1). Since the elements of both stacks will be intermixed among each other and you have to maintain whether a position belongs to stack1 or stack2 and if it is empty(enum).

When you are trying to insert an element into one of the stack you have to search for an empty slot and place the value over there (for this you might you might have skip elements of other stack which will be in between).

When you are trying to delete an element from one of the stack you have to mark the element as empty and find the element on the left side of the popped element which belongs to the corresponding stack and make it as top of the stack.

And also for checking full or empty it`s better to check with the sum of elements in both stacks.

Push and Pop would be O(n) instead of what you want as O(1).

If you still want to implement push and pop in O(1) and both stacks from same side of the array I suggest you to maintain top of both the stacks, next free index and previous/(next free index) for every element.

if element has been occupied it will point to previous index in stack else if it is free it will contain next free index.

Ex: free = 0; top1 = -1 , top2 = -1 next[i] = i+1 next[n-1] = -1 initially

checking for full is just full == -1

checking for stack emptiness would be top1 == -1

insert x into top 1

```
a[free] = x
next[free] = top1 // useful while poping
top1 = free
free = next[free]
```

popping from stack1

```
temp = top1 // storing top since we have to make this index as free and point next of this index to previous free
top1 = next[top1] // setting previous element as top
next[temp] = free
free = temp
```

Drawback for this implementation is we are using O(n) extra memory

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved by allocating even_indexes to Stack1 and Odd indexes to Stack2. This can potentially solve the stack overflow problem with the use of dynamic array size implementation. Top1 and top2 for both stacks will always point to indexes at respective even and odd position. For different size stacks we will have NONE at corresponding position

## Implement two stack using one list in python

## #Idea is to have o and even indexes for Stack1 and odd indexes for Stack 2

class ImplementTwoStacks:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.array = [None for count in range(2)]
    self.top1 = 0
    self.top2 = 1

def len_array(self):
    return len(self.array)

def pushStack1(self, item):
    if self.top1 == self.len_array() - 2:
        self.array = self.array + [None for count in range(10)]
    if self.top1 == 0:
        self.array[self.top1] = item
        self.top1 += 2
        return

    self.array[self.top1] = item
    self.top1 += 2
    return

def pushStack2(self, item):
    #all odd index
    if self.top2 == self.len_array() - 1:
        self.array = self.array.extend([1 for count in range(10)])

    if self.top2 ==1:
        self.array[self.top2] = item
        self.top2 += 2
        return

    self.array[self.top2] = item
    self.top2 += 2

    return

def popStack1(self):

    if self.top1 == 0:
        temp = self.array[self.top1]
        self.array[self.top1] = None
        return temp

    self.top1 -= 2
    temp = self.array[self.top1]
    self.array[self.top1] = None
    return temp

def popStack2(self):
    if self.top2 ==1:
        temp = self.array[self.top2]
        self.array[self.top2] = None
        return temp

    self.top2 -= 2
    temp = self.array[self.top2]
    self.array[self.top2] = None
    return temp


def display_stack1(self):

    for item in self.array[0:len(self.array):2]:
        if item:
            print(item, "", end= "->")

def display_stack2(self):
    for item in self.array[1:len(self.array):2]:
        if item:
            print(item, "", end="->")
```